# Incrementing Variable in a foldLeft

Tags: arrays, scala, increment, accumulator

I have Scala code like this

```scala
var i = 1
for(e <- array) {
    acc += e * i
    i += 1
}
```

I need to multiply the first element in the array by 1, the next by 2, the next by 3 and so on adding it all into an accumulator. I feel that there is a better way of doing this in Scala, maybe even with folding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val x = List(1,1,1,1,1,1)
(((0,1) /: x){case ((acc, mult), l) => (acc + (l * mult), mult + 1) })._1
```

In other words, starting with an accumulator of 0 and a multiplier of 1, fold each element of the list in, changing the accumulator to `acc + (l * mult)` and incrementing the multiplier by 1. We get the final multiplier out at the end as well, so we call `._1` to just get the accumulator.

Edit: As @RexKerr points in his answer below (and the comment), if performance is a major concern then you're better off using an explicit recursive method.

Answer (score 15):

"Better" depends on what your goals are.  Short and clear?  Probably

```
{ for (i <- array.indices; e = array(i)) yield (i+1)*e }.sum
```

or

```
array.indices.map(i => (i+1)*array(i)).sum
```

(or slightly faster, since you create the intermediates as you go:

```
array.indices.iterator.map(i => (i+1)*array(i)).sum
```

).

You should usually be short and clear.

Fast?  Then you'll need to go old-school:

```
var i = 0
var acc = 0
while (i < array.length) {
  acc += (i+1)*array(i)
  i += 1
}
```

or use recursion

```
def sum(a: Array[Int], i: Int = 0, acc: Int = 0): Int =
  if (i >= a.length) acc else sum(a, i+1, (i+1)*a(i) + acc)
sum(array)
```

Comment: Is explicit recursion likely to be any faster than a fold? Only advantage I can see is not allocating the tuple...

Comment: @Impredicative - If you're doing lightweight operations like addition of integers, not allocating the tuple is huge (10x speedup).  Also, collections are not specialized for primitives which means every integer has to be boxed, while recursion can use primitive types.  Also huge (both together gives ~20x-30x speedup).

Comment: Hey @Rex, do you mind explaining why you are mapping over the iterator in the 3rd example? Mapping over the indices seems to do the trick.

Comment: @DaMainBoss - The 2nd example creates a whole new collection (a `Vector`, actually) to store the intermediate results.  Using an `iterator` prevents this--it does the mapping on the fly--so despite the extra overhead from advancing from item to item, it's faster overall.  But it's _not as short and clear_, so only do it if the overhead of the extra collection is a problem.  (I think it is clearer than a fold, though.)

Comment: Cool, I'll start using that more often now... Cheers!

Comment: The third suggestion is directly equivalent to the first. The second one shows it's all too easy to unintentionally need wasteful intermediate state.

Comment: @Rick-777 - The first and second suggestions are equivalent.  Plus you're already wastefully boxing integers, so who's counting?

Comment: Sorry to nit-pick over trivia, but the first has an implied call to get the iterator, so it's equivalent to the third.

Comment: @Rick-777 - Good grief, why do you think that?  Go check `-Xprint:typer` or some bytecode!  Also, did you realize that it packs the `e` in a tuple?

Answer (score 10):

I prefer zipWithIndex which is simpler to read:

```
array.zipWithIndex.map { case (e, i) => e * (i + 1) }.sum
```

Comment: but then you iterate over the array twice from my understanding of that method, correct?

Comment: Three times. zipWithIndex and map both iterate over the array and sum is implemented via foldLeft. So my approach is certainly not the fastest

Comment: If you use .view on array first, it will only be one pass, but you have to deal with the overhead of .view.  Pick your poison.

Comment: @nnythm could you expand on this answer a bit? Why does using .view remove the need for the compiler to iterate over the array three times for .zipWithIndex, .map and .sum?

Comment: @chrissphinx .view makes the functions get lazily evaluated, so I don't think zipWithIndex and the map don't evaluated until sum time.  At that time, each item in the new array that's getting summed over is computed one by one, so the array is only iterated over once.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if what I suggest is a better way to do it or not, as it is more functional (== it will perform slower):

`(0 /: (array zipWithIndex)) {(a, i) => (i._1 * (i._2 + 1)) + a}`

This does perform foldLeft on an array which is produced by zipWithIndex method in http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array

zipWithIndex simply zips the elements of a collection with their indices.